# How do I repeatedly loop dispatch_after statements?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I want to have a for loop with `dispatch_after` statements in them. Problem is that the dispatch_after calls don't seem to go in line with the for loop. In other words, I want it to only start the next iteration of the for loop after the statements in the `dispatch_after` block have executed.

How would I do this?

### Use Case

I want to present words on screen. Traditionally I show one word per second. But depending on the word length, I now want to show longer words for slightly longer, and shorter words for slightly less time. I want to present a word, wait a little while (depending on how long the word is) then present the next word, wait a little while, then the next, etc.

Comment: You need to describe what you are actually trying to accomplish so people can offer appropriate solutions.

Comment: Updated, sorry for the ambiguity.

Comment: Why are you repeating your previous question on this topic?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080927/what-is-the-best-way-performance-wise-to-flash-things-at-a-varying-speed

Comment: I felt this was a different, more specific question.

Comment: What about just using old-school `NSThread`? I posted an answer for that. I think it's simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve this. Naturally, you will need to replace my NSLog with the code to show the word, and replace my simple `0.05 * word.length` function with whatever function you're using to determine delay, but this should do the trick, and do it without blocking the presenting thread.

```
- (void)presentWord: (NSString*)word
{
    // Create a private, serial queue. This will preserve the ordering of the words
    static dispatch_queue_t wordQueue = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        wordQueue = dispatch_queue_create(NULL, DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    });

    dispatch_async(wordQueue, ^{
        // Suspend the queue
        dispatch_suspend(wordQueue);

        // Show the word...
        NSLog(@"Now showing word: %@", word);

        // Calculate the delay until the next word should be shown...
        const NSTimeInterval timeToShow = 0.05 * word.length; // Or whatever your delay function is...

        // Have dispatch_after call us after that amount of time to resume the wordQueue.
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(timeToShow * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            dispatch_resume(wordQueue);
        });
    });
}

// There's nothing special here. Just split up a longer string into words, and pass them
// to presentWord: one at a time.
- (void)presentSentence: (NSString*)string
{
    NSArray* components = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    [components enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [self presentWord: obj];
    }];
}
```

EDIT: The way this works is that I'm using a serial queue to maintain the ordering of the words.  When you submit a word to `-presentWords` it enqueues a block at the "back" of `wordQueue`. When that block begins execution, you know that `wordQueue` is not suspended (because you're in a block that's executing on `wordQueue`) and the first thing we do is suspend `wordQueue`. Since this block is already "in flight" it will run to completion, but no other blocks will be run from `wordQueue` until someone resumes it. After suspending the queue, we display the word. It will remain displayed until something else is displayed. Then, we calculate the delay based on the length of the word we just started showing, and set up a `dispatch_after` to resume `wordQueue` after that time has passed. When the serial queue is resumed, the block for the next word begins executing, suspends the queue and the whole process repeats itself.

Comment: @DougSmith Added comments and explanation. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: @DougSmith posted sample add to GitHub: https://github.com/ipmcc/SOExamples/tree/master/timedwords

Answer (score 7):

Prints 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, one digit per second.

```
    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0UL);
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
        dispatch_async(queue,^{
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1LL * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"%d",i);
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // show label on screen
                });
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
            });
        });
    }
```

If you state your use case, maybe there are other ways to accomplish what you are trying to do.

---

You could also accumulate the delay time in advance and send all blocks.

```
    (1) __block double delay = 0;
    (2) dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0UL);
    (3) for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    (4) delay += 1LL * NSEC_PER_SEC; // replace 1 second with something related to the length of your word
    (5) dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delay), queue, ^{
            NSLog(@"%d",i);
    (6)     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // show label on screen
            });
        });
    }
```

1. Mark the variable __block so it can be modified inside the block
2. Get hold of one of the predefined queues of the system. A queue holds a number of anonymous pieces of code (called “blocks”) that are executed in turn.
3. Loop.
4. Add one second. You should replace that 1 with something else. For example, .10*[word length] will result in 1 second pause if the word has 10 letters.
5. Put the following code (aka “block”) in the “queue” after the given amount of “delay” seconds. The queue will automatically run the blocks of code that you put on it. This line is like saying, “run this after a delay”.
6. Anytime you are in the background (like here, because “queue” is probably running on a background thread) and you want to change the user interface, you have to run the code in the main queue, because UIKit is not a thread-safe library (meaning, not designed to run correctly if you call it from different threads).

Comment: Could you explain what the code is doing by chance? I'm a little confused.

Comment: I added some comments for the second example.

Comment: How would this work if I needed to have one be delayed 1.3 seconds, the next 0.8 seconds, and the third 0.05 seconds, for instance?

Comment: You would write `delay += 1.3 * 1LL * NSEC_PER_SEC;` But since it changes on every iteration, you want to replace 1.3 with a calculated value, in your example, depending on your word length. Something like [word length]*.1 so `delay += [word length]*.1 * 1LL * NSEC_PER_SEC;`

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2**

Here's a GCD-based version:

```
@interface Test : NSObject
@property ( nonatomic, copy ) NSArray * wordlist ;
@property ( nonatomic ) volatile BOOL cancelled ;

-(void)run ;
-(void)cancel ;

@end

@implementation Test

-(void)displayWords:(NSArray*)words
{
    NSLog(@"word=%@\n", words[0] ) ;
    if ( words.count > 1 && !self.cancelled )
    {
        words = [ words subarrayWithRange:(NSRange){ 1, words.count - 1 } ] ;

        double              delayInSeconds = 1.0;       // calculate delay until next word here
        dispatch_time_t     popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));

        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [ self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector( displayWords: ) withObject:words waitUntilDone:NO ] ;
        });
    }
}

-(void)run
{
    [ self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector( displayWords: ) withObject:self.wordlist waitUntilDone:NO ] ;
}

-(void)cancel
{
    self.cancelled = YES ;
}

@end
```

This performs the display on the main thread--that's a requirement if you're using UIKit to draw your text.

This is similar to other answers, but uses just the default queue without using `dispatch_resume()` and `dispatch_suspend()`

---

You could use `NSThread`. I think this is very understandable:

```
@interface Thread : NSThread
@property ( nonatomic, copy ) NSArray * wordlist ;
@end

@implementation Thread

// runs on main thread
-(void)displayWord:(NSString*)word
{
    // code to display word goes here
}

-(void)main
{
    for( NSString * word in self.wordlist )
    {
        if ( self.isCancelled ) { return ; }
        [ self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector( displayWord: ) withObject:word waitUntilDone:NO ] ;
        [ NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0 ] ; // replace with desired pause... (could be based on word length)
    }
}

@end
```

To use:

```
Thread * thread = [[ Thread alloc ] init] ;
thread.wordlist = @[ @"one", @"two", @"three" ] ;
[ thread start ] ;
```

Comment: This may be very understandable, but it's a pretty bad way to do it.  You're starting a thread which is just going to sit there asleep most of the time. This is a waste of thread. A process can only have so many threads, and there are FAR better, more idiomatic ways to do this. Plus, OP tagged his post with `grand-central-dispatch` which this answer does not utilize.

Comment: I don't think it's a bad way. The thread will be torn down when the work is done. but yes, it's not GCD.

Comment: Ok I posted a real GCD version.