# NSTimer : Update Label after switch View doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, label, progress-bar, nstimer

I want to use NSTimer as a Countdown. The counter works fine;-)!
But I I switch to another viewController the timer doesn't runs in "foreground" - so the label isn't updated.... after coming back to this view.

My NSLOG shows that the timer is still runnig, like I want ;-)

So in whicht way I have to work, that my timer update my label?

Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)startClock:(id)sender {
globalTimer = 20;

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                          target:self
                                        selector:@selector(updateCircularProgressBar)
                                        userInfo:nil
                                         repeats:YES];


 }


    - (void)updateCircularProgressBar
{
 // Values to be passed on to Circular Progress Bar
 if (globalTimer > 0 && globalTimer <= 1200) {
     globalTimer--;
     minutesLeft = globalTimer / 60;
     secondsLeft = globalTimer % 60;

     [self drawCircularProgressBarWithMinutesLeft:minutesLeft secondsLeft:secondsLeft];
     NSLog(@"Time left: %02d:%02d", minutesLeft, secondsLeft);
 } 
 else {
     [self drawCircularProgressBarWithMinutesLeft:0 secondsLeft:0];
     [timer invalidate];
 }
}
```

I tested to run the "updateCircularProgressBar" in my viewDidLoad but this shows NO result...
THX for Help
UPDATE more with more Code:

```
/*-------------------- TIMER --------------------*/
// Draws the progress circles on top of the already painted background
- (void)drawCircularProgressBarWithMinutesLeft:(NSInteger)minutes secondsLeft:(NSInteger)seconds
{ 
// Removing unused view to prevent them from stacking up
for (id subView in [self.view subviews]) {
 if ([subView isKindOfClass:[CircularProgressTimer class]]) {
         [subView removeFromSuperview];
     }
 }

// Init our view and set current circular progress bar value
 CGRect progressBarFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 180);
 progressTimerView = [[CircularProgressTimer alloc] initWithFrame:progressBarFrame];
 [progressTimerView setCenter:CGPointMake(160, 210)];
 [progressTimerView setPercent:seconds];
if (minutes == 0 && seconds <= 0) {
   [progressTimerView setInstanceColor:[UIColor magentaColor]];
}


// Here, setting the minutes left before adding it to the parent view
 [progressTimerView setMinutesLeft:minutesLeft];
 [progressTimerView setSecondsLeft:secondsLeft];
 [self.view addSubview:progressTimerView];
 progressTimerView = nil;
}
```

The label is in another file (CircularProgressTimer) which controls the progessbar...

Comment: Perhaps you might have better luck using dispatch_ methods as in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19096797/1014164

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand... So, you are using two view controllers? Where is the label that you are talking about? On both view controllers? How do you navigate between the view controllers? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: updated the code... ;-) I use different Controller (in one controller I use this timer) and one class with the CircularProgressTimer...